# Is this South Korean animation TV series regarded as anime due to its similar japanese animation style?

Tags: anime-production, anime-history

Its a South Korean animation TV series called ''Spheres'' and it is has strong similarities of Japanese animation techniques used in the series and art style that looks similar to anime

[image]

[image]

[image]

Should we regard this as anime like Japan's due its animation styles and techniques that Japanese use and despite being an animation of non Japanese origin?

Comment: Definitely not.  There is no **way** you would call it an "anime"...